# Tabulator - Progressive Ajax Loading : applying a filter after all pages are received

Tags: tabulator

I am using Tabulator 4.9 to display a table of files. As there can be a lot of files, I am progressively loading the data into the table using `ajaxProgressiveLoad:"load"` and returning data chunked into pages.
The user should be able to refresh the list of files, however, if the table is filtered in the headers, after refresh only the first page received will be filtered, and the rest of the data added subsequently is not filtered.

How can I force-filter the data returned in all pages without filtering server-side?
I was looking for a callback after all the pages are loaded but can't seem to find one.

I tried the following:

- force filter in `dataLoaded` callback => doesn't work. The callback is called only after the first page
- force filter in `rowAdded` callback => works but as it's executed for every file, takes a while

In the meantime I modified the tabulator.js code to get this to work, by adding `this.table.refreshFilter();` after `addRows()` below. Is there a better way to go about this?

```
case "progressive_load":

    if (this.page == 1) {
        this.table.rowManager.setData(data[this.dataReceivedNames.data], false, this.initialLoad && this.page == 1);
    } else {
        this.table.rowManager.addRows(data[this.dataReceivedNames.data]);
        this.table.refreshFilter();
    }

    if (this.page < this.max) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.nextPage().then(function () {}).catch(function () { });
        }, self.table.options.ajaxProgressiveLoadDelay);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Personally, I'd just add your own custom AJAX pagination loader, even if it pretty well copies the stock one, and then once the last page is loaded (and you know this from the response body for Tabulator Pagination) then apply your filters.

Also, I would put in an Enhancement Request on the GitHUB page, and this seems worthy of a Notifcation when the Nth page has been loaded (in your case, N=last)

Comment: oh, what about getPage() and getPageMax() ? Could that be used in your dataLoaded callback to determine if its finished loading ?